# Kendo UI Styling not working in .NET Core

Tags: kendo-ui, .net-core, styling

I'm porting an MVC application that uses Kendo UI to .NET Core.  The existing application has considerable styling created by another team and the ported application needs to look like the old one.  The new application is not picking up the old styles (I've double checked the css files and I'm sure they're all in the right location).  My source looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<FundViewModel>()
                                .Name("grid")

                                    ....
```

When I look at the HTML source on the old code, I see:

```
<div class="k-widget k-grid" id="grid">
```

Wrapping the kendoGrid object.  When I look at the HTML source for the new code, I see:

```
<div id="grid" name="grid">
```

Around the grid.  Is there a difference between the MVC and .NET Core products in the way the default styles are specified?  Is there any reference reading material that talks about styling in the .NET Core product?  Is there a way to explicitly state what styles are used?

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is rather related with the javascript files that are most probably not loaded correctly. You can refer to [this help](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/getting-started) topic where in sections 7 and 8 there are steps about the script resources that are needed. Otherwise the Grid is working correctly on its demo [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/index).

Comment: That's the page I used to put together the demo program.  All the style sheets are where they're supposed to be.  Kendo UI seems to work just fine out of the box with their styles.  The problem is that a .NET MVC program built with customized styles doesn't work when ported to .NET Core.

Comment: Seems like a custom issue that have to be debugger locally - if it can be isolated in a dojo or a sample it would be useful.